# How to reuse strings in C without old values showing up in the memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm sure this is extremely simple and probably gets asked a lot but this is driving me absolutely crazy and I cant even figure out how to properly word my question to search for an answer.

Basically, I'm reading a txt file (in C) and identifying how many times a word appears.

1. I grab an entire line from the txt file using getLine();
2. copy every character to a string until I reach a space
3. Sends the new string to another function that parses out invalid characters

The problem I'm running into is each time it goes through the loop, it keeps the old characters in the string and just replaces them. I'm trying to set this up so after a word is passed to parseWord, that temporary string named `newWord` is reset (and empty). Likewise, `cleanWord` in the `parseWord` function is doing the same thing.

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, but I just don't understand how to and its becoming extremely frustrating. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
void readFiles(FILE *file1, List *theList, int fileNum) {
    int i, lineIndex;
    char *newLine;

    size_t lineLength = 0;
    while(lineLength=getline(&newLine, &lineLength, file1)>0){
        lineIndex = 0;
        i = 0;
        char *newWord;//saves individual words
        while(newLine[lineIndex] != '\0'){   //move to new space
            if(newLine[lineIndex] == ' '){
                //insert(&theList, parseWord(i, newWord), fileNum);
                parseWord(i, newWord);
                i = 0;
            }else{
                newWord[i] = newLine[lineIndex];
                i++;
            }
            lineIndex++;
        }
    }
}

char *parseWord(int theLen, char *theWord){
    char cleanWord[theLen]; //the word without other stuff
    char *finalWord;
    int i, j;
    for(j = i = 0; i < theLen; i++) {
        char tmp = theWord[i];

        if (tmp >= 'A' && tmp <= 'Z') {
            cleanWord[j] = tolower((unsigned char) theWord[i]);
            j++;
        } else if ((tmp >= 'a' && tmp <= 'z') || tmp == 39 || tmp == 45) {
            cleanWord[j] = theWord[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return strcpy(finalWord, cleanWord);

    }
```

For example: the first line being read is: `The Red Badge of Courage`

when the word gets passed into the second fuction, for `theWord` I get:

1. The
2. Red
3. Badge
4. ofdge (this should be of)

Comment: `while(newLine[lineIndex] = '\0';` Is this the actual code? Did you mean `while(newLine[lineIndex] != '\0') { /* body */ }`?

Comment: No, but good catch. The formatting on this website was causing me a lot of issues so I just kinda typed it out real quick since copying wasn't working.

Comment: Note, your indentation for the `else` should be at the same level as the `if` to make things easier to follow. The quick fix is to add `cleanWord[j] = theWord[i] = '\0';` to the end of `parseWord()`.

Comment: Just block indent everything by 4-spaces and paste it in. Nothing else required.

Comment: Oops, I noticed you don't allocate memory for `cleanWord`. Furthermore, `isupper()` and `islower()` exist too, and `if(isalpha(tmp)) cleanWord[j++] = tolower(tmp);` is more idiomatic than the current `if/else`.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can use `memset()` to zero an array or allocation, but why not just be sure to write a terminating `\0` when copying characters to the temporary array? It doesn't matter what follows the null terminator of a string.

Comment: @DavidBowling yeah its absolutely an XY problem but its kind of difficult to figure out WHAT I'm doing wrong. I'm just a student and this wasn't remotely covered by my instructor so I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I'll try adding the '\0' and hopefully that will help. I'm really just trying to figure out the proper way of reusing a string without this issue so I can learn.

Comment: @TannerDanger -- why have you reversed my edit which included the code from your Pastebin link? Don't post links to code, post actual code. There are many reasons for this; posting links to code is considered bad etiquette on SO. Rolling back.

Comment: @DavidBowling My mistake, I don't use this website much I didn't realize that was you. I thought that I just didn't hit submit on my edit and it was still showing the old code I wrote. Your solution of adding the '\0' to the end of the string when copying solved my problem  for all intents and purposes. Thanks for doing that.

Comment: @TannerDanger -- Ah. Good, glad that helped. I noticed when you removed the initial approximate code and added the link, so I just edited to put the code in your question since that is what is preferred around here. For future reference, you can copy-paste code from your text editor into the body of your question, select the text with your mouse, then press CTRL-k to put it in a code block.

Comment: In `readFiles()`, you have an error in your loop: `while(lineLength=getline(&newLine, &lineLength, file1)>0)` should be `while ((lineLength = getline(&newLine, &lineLength, file1)) > 0)` where the crucial change is not the spacing but the extra parentheses around the assignment.  Your 'lineLength` is being set to `1` on each iteration because of the rules of precedence.  However, you don't use `lineLength`, so maybe it doesn't matter; you might be better off losing the variable altogether: `while (getline(&newLine, &lineLength, file1) > 0)` would suffice — unless your text file has null bytes.

Comment: `strcpy` looks for a termination char `\0` in your `parseWord` function before the return statment you should set `cleanWord[j] = '\0'`

Comment: @Dagan that is actually the solution I came up with. My problem was that I was doing cleanWord = '\0'; and not cleanWord[j] = '\0';  which was causing a segfault. Thanks for confirming that was the way I should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers in the comments all of which helped me solve my problem.

I started adding a null terminating character to the end of each string copy which helped eliminate unnecessary characters.

I still don't quite understand the proper method for reusing strings but for all intents and purposes, my problem was solved. Thanks everyone.

Note: Part of my problem was I was trying to reset each string by using

```
cleanWord = '\0';
```

which was causing a segfault the next time it tried to assign a char to it.

Comment: It seems that what you  were missing is that a string is a null-terminated character array in C. That means that a character array by itself is _not_ a string, and it also means that the `'\0'` character is _part_ of the string. Maybe it would be better to say that a string is a null-terminated character _subarray_. When you add the `'\0'` you terminate the string, and any characters which follow the `'\0'` in the larger character array (including previous `'\0'` characters) are no longer part of the _string_.

Comment: Also, I see no memory allocated for `newWord` or `finalWord`. This will lead to undefined behavior when you attempt to write even one character through these pointers. This UB might manifest as a segmentation fault, but the code might also appear to work in some circumstances. You should fix this if you haven't already. This could be as simple as `char newWord[1000];` and `char finalWord[1000];'`. I see no obvious reason for dynamic allocation here, and 1000 is probably plenty generous for reasonable word sizes. Still, code should also check array bounds.

Comment: @DavidBowling thanks for all of your help. I ended up solving the problem using a combination of the advice given, especially yours. After using java for 3 years it gets very frustrating trying to do something that should be so simple. Thanks for all the advice and helping me actually. understand the problem and not just telling me the errors in my code.